# What does it mean when the computer is repeating long beeps?

Tags: troubleshooting, noise

When I start my really old computer, it continuously and regularly emits long beeps- what does this mean?

intel brand motherboard, the copyright is 1996, really don't know much else about the computer.

Comment: Does the computer start at all? Does your monitor display anything? Are you able to boot into your operating system?

Answer (score 2):

A motherboard may use the computer speaker to emit a number of beeps (long, short, or a combination of the two) to alert the user of some hardware problem.

It may be a fan which stopped working, a card badly inserted, a failing RAM module, and so on.

You should try to find the exact model of your motherboard, and then search the Internet for its manual - in the "Troubleshooting" section there will probably be a list of "beep" combinations, together with their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The *buffer* is overflowing. This is *usually* the result of the *keyboard* buffer overflowing. A stuck key, or a broken keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - Long Beep = Computer buggered.

Technical answer - If it continuously emits long beeps (repeatedly) it is usually down to a short / motherboard problem such as a card or module has become dislodged - down to inconsistent power.

If you want to read about different types of beeps, [I recommend this page](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm).

Answer (score 0):

While this thread is pretty old and somewhat dead - I thought I'd drop my .02 in the bucket.

On a PC with a Phoenix BIOS, I've had this problem happen because I had a broken keyboard plugged in.  So it CAN be something simpler than a totally hosed computer.  I swapped out a different keyboard and it booted up just fine.

The beep code page William referenced is helpful - though it doesn't have anything on what I specifically experienced...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump a very old thread. If it is a very old computer and hasn’t been started in a long time, it’s probably got a dead CMOS battery. Usually, it is a large button cell CR2032 3 volt battery. I had the same problem with an old Micron PC a few minutes ago and this fixed it.